# Folder comparison

Tags: bash, directory

I have two folders with similar subfolder structures, which I would like to compare. For example:

```
A 
├── child-1
├── child-2
├── child-3
├── child-4
├── child-5
```

and

```
B 
├── child-1-some-text
├── child-2-more-text
├── child-3-nothing
├── child-6-random-text
├── child-7-more-random-text
```

I would like to list all those subfolders from `A` which are prefix for a subfolder in `B` and list corresponding subfolders from `B` as well. The expected output is

```
child-1 -- child-1-some-text
child-2 -- child-2-more-text
child-3 -- child-3-nothing
```

A secondary requirement: If multiple matches in `B`, then it should give an error / warning.

### My **solution**:

```
cd A
for f in `ls -d */`; 
do
    cd B;
    new_dirs=(`ls -1d $f*`);
    cd -;
    if [ ${#new_dirs[@]} -eq 0 ]
    then
        ## DO_Nothing
        continue;
    elif  [ ${#new_dirs[@]} -gt 1 ]
    then
        echo "Multiple matches to $f";
        continue;
    else
        echo "Unique Match found to $f -- ${new_dirs[0]}";
        continue;
    fi;    
done
```

### Problem:

For those values of `$f`, which have no corresponding subfolders in `B`, the array construction is giving me an error. e.g.:

> ls: cannot access 'child-4*': No such file or directory

### Question

- How to get rid of these errors?
- Is there **better** way to achieve the goal(s) then the one in my code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: +1 for providing an almost working solution!

Comment: This is not an answer to your specific question, but you can use `diff -rq DIR1 DIR2` to compare not just directory structure, but file contents.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### The better way

[Don't parse `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs); use globs instead. In fact you're already using globs, just wrapping them in `ls`, which is pointless. You just need `nullglob` turned on for when there are no matches.

Also avoiding `cd` simplifies things.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

dir1=A
dir2=B

for dir in "$dir1"/*/; do
    basename="$(basename -- "$dir")"
    dirs_match=( "$dir2/$basename"*/ )
    case ${#dirs_match[@]} in
    0)
        ;;
    1)
        echo "Unique match for $dir: ${dirs_match[*]}"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Multiple matches for $dir: ${dirs_match[*]}" >&2
        ;;
    esac
done
```

Output:

```
Unique match for A/child-1/: B/child-1-some-text/
Unique match for A/child-2/: B/child-2-more-text/
Multiple matches for A/child-3/: B/child-3-nothing/ B/child-3-something/
```

I added `B/child-3-something` to test the secondary requirement. This creates the directory structure for testing:

```
mkdir -p A/child-{1..5} B/child-{1-some-text,2-more-text,3-nothing,3-something,6-random-text,7-more-random-text}
```

By the way, [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) is very useful for finding problems in shell scripts.

Comment: ShellCheck.net is interesting, do you know if it uploads everything to it's own servers, or is it all done locally? Just wondering about the privacy of entered info. [Installing the `shellcheck` package would be the most secure]

Comment: @Xen2050 Just tried toggling my internet off while on the site, and it seems to upload. I would imagine it doesn't keep it, but not sure. And yes the package is good; I use [an Atom plugin](https://atom.io/packages/linter-shellcheck) that uses it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. And also tons of thanks for pointing towards `ShellCheck`. I loved the part where it not only tells you your errors, but also gives suggestions! @Xen2050, about the uploading part, I just installed `shellcheck` using `apt` and then disabled network. It seems to be working **without internet**.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `ls` on a non existent folder throws the error message that you encountered. The easy way is to just ignore this by replacing line 5 in your script with this: `` new_dirs=(`ls -1d $f* 2> /dev/null`); ``.

Comment: Have you tested this? Stderr seems to get ignored by default, when I run `t=(\`echo ok; echo err 1>&2\`)` $t (or `${t[@]}`) only contains ok, err is seen in the terminal but not saved anyway. Or is there something funny about my test?